# Variable not being read correctly

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

I try to do the script below

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set MYFILE=D:\Working Dir\Home Usage Working\patch me.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 skip=2" %%A in (!MYFILE!) do (
Echo %%A
Echo %%B
Echo %%C
)
endlocal
```

This is not working for me. I know the issues is with spaces in the path name. I have tired putting quotes around "!MYFILE!" but that does not work.

How do I make this work?

Comment: It' s"not working for you" in what way?  What happens when you run it?

Comment: Now after doing as suggested, it is not reading the actual file but treating it as a text. Current results is that after every space it is being split.


## Formatting inside this commenting box is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the script "read" the text file. What I ended up doing was

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set MYFILE=D:\Working Dir\Home Usage Working\patch me.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 usebackq skip=2" %%A in ("!MYFILE!") do ( 
Echo %%A 
Echo %%B 
Echo %%C
) 
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the quotes around the path when you declare MyFile, not around the variable when you use it.

So change `set MYFILE=D:\Working Dir\Home Usage Working\patch me.txt` to `set MYFILE="D:\Working Dir\Home Usage Working\patch me.txt"`